# How to call an intent from widget in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to add play music button to my widget. However, when I click button from widget I get

> "Could not find an intent with identifier PlayerIntent,
> mangledTypeName: Optional("21PlayerWidgetExtension0A6IntentV")"

error. If I use intent from inside the app I get

> PlayerIntent failed to execute with error: The operation couldn’t be
> completed. (AppIntents.AppIntentError error 1.)

I added PlayerIntent to both app and widget targets.

```
struct PlayerIntent: AudioStartingIntent {
static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "PlayerIntent"
static var description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("Plays a widget sound")

@Parameter(title: "Sound")
var sound: String

init() {}

init(sound: String) {
    self.sound = ""
}

@MainActor
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    Player.shared.play()
    return .result()
}}
```

I created PlayerIntent by adding an "App Intents Extensions" target. Otherwise, I can't even see this error in console.

**Update:** I get this error even in Apple's example app Emoji Rangers.